Non-closed subgroup of non-simply connected matrix Lie group
The question stems from B.C. Hall's textbook Lie groups, Lie algebras, and representations, and is given in chapter 5, exercise 14.c. I am trying to come up with a counterexample to the statement "If $G$ is a simply connected matrix Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ is an ideal in $\mathfrak{g}$, then the connected Lie subgroup $H$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{h}$ is closed", when the assumption that $G$ is simply connected is dropped.
The closest I was able to get thus far is the irrational winding of the torus discussed in the Wikipedia article, and discussed in page 5 of the book, (where $G=\mathbb{T}^2$, $H=\{\operatorname{diag}(e^{2\pi i\theta},e^{2\pi i\theta a}), \theta\in\mathbb{R}\}$, $a$ irrational) however my contention is the fact that the Lie subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ given by $\mathfrak{h}=\{\operatorname{diag}(i\theta, i\theta a), \theta \in \mathbb R\}$ in this case is not an ideal in $\mathfrak{g}$.
How can I approach this problem?
